# filling a 2d array in a 1d array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Im reading a text file like this:

```
wwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wffbbbbbbbbbffw
wf1bwbwbwbwbwfw
wbbbbbbbbbbbbbw
wbwbwbwbwbwbwbw
wbbbbbbbbbbbbbw
wbwbwbwbwbwbwbw
wbbbbbbbbbbbbbw
wbwbwbwbwbwbwbw
wbbbbbbbbbbbbbw
wbwbwbwbwbwbwbw
wbbbbbbbbbbbbbw
```

or

```
fffffffffffffff
wffffffffffffff
fwfffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
ff1ffffwfffffff
fffffffwfffffff
fffffffwfffffff
fffffffwfffffff
fffffffffffffff
fff2fffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
wffffffffffffff
fwfffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffwfffffff
fffffffwfffffff
fffffffwfffffff
fffffffwfffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffff
```

Then I get the `x` and the `y` of this file by doing a `strlen` of the first string for `y` and the number of lines for `x` :

```
void            Map::get_size_map(char *dat_name)
{
  std::ifstream ifs;
  int x;
  int y;
  char c;

  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  c = 0;
  ifs.open (dat_name, std::ifstream::in);
  if(ifs.is_open())
    {
      while(!ifs.eof())
        {
          c = ifs.get();
          if(y == 0 && c != '\n')
            x++;
          if(c == '\n')
            y++;
        }
    }
  ifs.close();
  this->x_map = x;
  this->y_map = y;
}
```

Now in my program I wanna access let's say the `[4][2]` position of my map, for that I made a function returning the correct place in my 1d array with my func like this :

```
int Map::fix_Pos(int x, int y)
{
  int x_r;
  int y_r;

  x_r = x * this->x_map;
  return (x_r + y);
}
```

It works well for the first `text(map)` but for the second I get strange behavior on the first move when I start to move inside the map

Comment: What should `fix_pos` return, the index of [4, 2] if all the values were in a 1D array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int Map::fix_Pos(int x, int y)
{
  int x_r;
  int y_r;

  x_r = x * this->x_map;
  return (x_r + y);
}
```

Actually you multiply you're horizontal line (which is X) and add your horizontal line (which is Y). By doing you'll get the opposite position of you're map.

Try to multiply your number of vertical line (Y) with the size of your line and add the rest of you're horizontal line.

*Try this :*

```
int Map::fix_Pos(int x, int y)
{
  return (y * this->x_map + x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be one of the following (depending of your representation):

```
int Map::fix_Pos(int x, int y) const
{
    return y * this->x_map + x;
}
```

or

```
int Map::fix_Pos(int x, int y) const
{
    return x * this->y_map + y;
}
```